# How to fix "Project build error: Non-parseable POM C:\xxx\apache-8.pom: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG..."

Tags: java, apache, pom.xml, rampart

I am consuming a SOAP web service. 
This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<parent>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
    <artifactId>rampart-project</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
<artifactId>rampart</artifactId>
<packaging>mar</packaging>
<name>Rampart - Mar</name>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/rampart/tags/v1.6.2</connection>
    <developerConnection>
        scm:svn:https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/rampart/tags/v1.6.2
    </developerConnection>
    <url>http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/axis/axis2/java/rampart/tags/v1.6.2</url>
</scm>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-mar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
                <moduleXmlFile>module.xml</moduleXmlFile>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>aar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifacts>
                            <artifact>
                                <file>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.mar</file>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifact>
                        </artifacts>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
        <artifactId>rampart-policy</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.rampart</groupId>
        <artifactId>rampart-trust</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


</project>
```

And this is the error:

Project build error: Non-parseable POM C:\xxx.m2\repository\org\apache\apache\8\apache-8.pom: entity reference name can not contain character =' (position: START_TAG seen ...tsByTagName(s)[0],\n    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=... @12:48)

Comment: Have a look at `C:\xxx.m2\repository\org\apache\apache\8\apache-8.pom`. It might have been corrupted during download, eg. by a proxy.

Comment: in the apache-8.pom:       <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-WVDKZS9');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

Comment: Yes, it's corrupted. Delete at least the folder `C:\xxx.m2\repository\org\apache` (if not `C:\xxx.m2\repository`) and try to build the project anew. The dependencies will be downloaded again, hopefully correct now. If not, fix your network setup or talk to the network admins if your working in a company and try again.